# Unable to upgrade

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I use civicrm 4.7.13 with joomla 3.6.5.

I can't upgrade to civicrm 4.7.14.

This is the log:

> 2017-01-04 18:01:43   Access  200 GET
>   /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer
>   HTTP/1.1  .../administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/extensions&reset=1&action=browse   Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 8.53 K  Apache-toegang
>
> 2017-01-04 18:01:50   Error   500 POST
>   /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=install
>   HTTP/1.1  .../administrator/index.php?option=com_installer    Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 1.51 K  Apache-toegang
>
> 2017-01-04 18:03:50   Warning mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120
>   seconds, referer:
>   .../administrator/index.php?option=com_installer              Foutmelding van
>   Apache
>
> 2017-01-04 18:03:50   Error   Premature end of script headers: index.php,
>   referer:
>   .../administrator/index.php?option=com_installer              Foutmelding van
>   Apache

I can uninstall and reinstall civicrm 4.7.13, but I can't uninstall 4.7.13 and install 4.7.14.
Any idea how I can solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: There might be some helpful information here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Not sure what I can do.I don't find a mod_fcgid on my hosting.
Max_execution_time is on highest level: 120

Comment: Can it help to add those lines tot .htaccess?
But which one? There are several .htaccess files!

Thank you

Comment: No luck with installing 4.7.15 neither:
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds
Premature end of script headers: index.php

But: When I go back in my browser, I can update the database and ... civicrm says i'm using 4.7.15 !

Strange, isn't it?